# Como relacionar duas listas, obtendo o valor de uma através do máximo da outra?

Tags: python, lista, loop

Estou preso num exercício que pede na entrada um número X de times que participam de um campeonato. Nas linhas posteriores é digitado o nome do time e sua pontuação. Na saída, o time que fez mais pontuações e a média.

Meu código atual é:

```
numero_de_times = int(raw_input())
gols = []
times = []
media1 = 0

for numeros in range(numero_de_times):
 time = str(raw_input())
 gol=  float(raw_input())
 media1 = media1 + gol
 media2 = media1 / numero_de_times

 times.append(time)
 gols.append(gol)


print "Time(s) com melhor ataque (%d gol(s)):" % max(gols)
print "%s" % 
print "Média de gols marcados: %.1f" % media2
```

Como podem ver eu criei uma lista vazia para guardar gols e os times. Se fosse apenas para saber a maior pontuação eu teria finalizado. Mas estou com dificuldade em retornar o nome do time e sua pontuação. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não há necessidade de armazenar todos os times e o seu número de gols - basta armazenar apenas um: o maior que você viu até agora - se, durante a execução, encontrar um número de gols maior do que tinha visto antes, troque o conteúdo da sua variável e passe a armazenar o novo campeão. No final, o campeão será o time que tiver sobrado na variável.

```
numero_de_times = int(raw_input())
soma = 0
maior = 0

for numeros in range(numero_de_times):
 time = str(raw_input())
 gol=  float(raw_input())
 soma = soma + gol
 if gol > maior:
    maior = gol
    nome_maior = time


print "Time com melhor ataque (%d gol(s)): %s" % (maior, nome_maior)
print "Média de gols marcados: %.1f" % (soma / numero_de_times)
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema pode ser resolvido com a utilização do método `index` da lista, que achará o índice onde se encontra o valor dentro da mesma. Por exemplo, na lista `lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, o resultado de `lista.index(3)` seria 2, indicando que o número 3 ocupa a posição 2 da lista.

Assim, sabendo o maior número de gols, com `max(gols)`, bastaria você verificar em que posição este valor está na lista e buscar nos times o valor na mesma posição:

```
>>> max_gols = max(gols)
>>> indice_vencedor = gols.index(max_gols)
>>> time_vencedor = times[indice_vencedor]
```

Então o valor de `time_vencedor` seria o nome do time que teve o maior número de gols.

---

Porém, não é interessante você manter dois valores correlacionados em estruturas distintas. Cada time possui um saldo de gols, então é melhor você guardar as informações de forma conjunta. No Python, para armazenar dados correlacionados de diferentes tipos utilizamos a tupla, ficando algo como `('time A', 10)` ou `('time B', 8)`. Mas como desta forma não fica muito claro o que representam os valores 10 e 8 você pode utilizar a tupla nomeada que deixa o código um pouco mais legível (**para versão 3.6+**):

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Time(NamedTuple):
    nome: str
    pontuação: int
```

Assim, você pode criar a lista de times:

```
x = int(input('Quantos times? '))

times = []

for i in range(x):
    nome = input('Nome: ')
    pontuação = int(input('Pontuação: '))
    time = Time(nome, pontuação)
    times.append(time)
```

E, finalmente, verificar o vencedor e a média da pontuação:

```
vencedor = max(times, key=lambda time: time.pontuação)
média = sum(time.pontuação for time in times) / len(times)
```

Exibindo na tela:

```
print(f'O time vencedor foi {vencedor.nome} com uma pontuação de {vencedor.pontuação}')
print(f'A média das pontuações foi {média}')
```

<sup>[Código funcionando](https://FocusedBlushingTrees.acwoss.repl.run) | Veja no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FocusedBlushingTrees)</sup>

Para qualquer time você poderá acessar os atributos `nome` e pontuação`, podendo também ordenar os times, gerando a classificação do campeonato:

```
for time in sorted(times, key=lambda time: time.pontuação, reverse=True):
    print(f'{time.nome}, com {time.pontuação} pontos')
```

O que geraria uma saída como:

```
>>> Quantos times?  3
>>> Nome:  Time A
>>> Pontuação:  13
>>> Nome:  Time B
>>> Pontuação:  15
>>> Nome:  Time C
>>> Pontuação:  10
Time B, com 15 pontos
Time A, com 13 pontos
Time C, com 10 pontos
```

<sup>[Código funcionando](https://JointSimultaneousGroupware.acwoss.repl.run) | Veja no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/JointSimultaneousGroupware)</sup>

Comment: Provavelmente num programa real armazenar todos os times seria necessário, mas para o que foi pedido é um desperdício de memória/processamento

Comment: @nosklo em Python, muita coisa é "desperdício" de memória :D E desta forma o código fica mais versátil para alterações futuras, tais como gerar a tabela de classificação. Sem persistir a pontuação separada de cada time não seria possível. É importante otimizar, mas primeiro é necessário ter problema de performance.

Comment: Não significa que precisa desperdiçar de propósito - sou a favor de desperdício se for para o código ficar mais fácil de entender, mas nesse caso, acho que é simples. Além disso é muito grande o desperdício nesse caso, são ordens de magnitude a mais. Imagina 10.000 times na memória vs 1 time; É bom já ir aprendendo a economizar